# Is there any difference in meaning: "Outside the wall was a ditch"

Tags: grammar

Is there any difference in meaning between: "Outside the wall was a ditch" and  "Outside the wall there was a ditch"

Comment: There is no difference in meaning.

Comment: Why not tell us what you think, too?

Comment: The fact of the ditch is the same in both utterances. Whether  **there was** adds some nuance that makes the utterance either more concrete or more impersonal is open to debate. http://linguistica.sns.it/RdL/25.1/intro_Bentley_&_alii.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in the meaning of those two phrases.

When reading the second one I get the sense that we're about to hear more about the ditch - that the ditch is not just a passing detail. That's the only difference I can think of looking at them together.